# ASP Boilerplate always shows the default error message

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, abp, asp.net-boilerplate

I am using ASP Boilerplate (MVC + Jquery) to develop two different online applications. It works very good but there is a problem with ABP exception handler in both of them:

It always shows the default error message (An error has occurred!    Error detail not sent by server) also in login validation.

How can I fix this problem?

I tried to debug this error and I realized that the error format that returned from server side is not a valid ABP error format.

Answer (score 0):

please check  in your web.config file that shoud be set to *On*

```
<customErrors mode="On" />
```